# terminate process immediately

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Consider the following code:

```
process := [ (Delay forSeconds: 10) wait ] 
    forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority.
process terminate.
process isTerminated. "--> false"
process resume. "process has been suspended but not terminated"
(Delay forSeconds: 10) wait.
process isTerminated "--> true"
```

As you can see, the process won't terminate until the block has been evaluated (i.e. after ten seconds in this case).

Is there a way to **immediately** terminate a process?
Also: does anyone have an idea why the block is evaluated in the first place?

**Edit:**
I can see why the block is evaluated. The problem with the above code is of course that I try to terminate the process before it has become active. Still, what if I don't want to wait for the delay to expire?

Comment: there is a ']' too much after the second wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending `terminate` your process is suspended (check by sending `isSuspended`) so it will not run unless resumed. You get false from `isTerminated` because the process did not have a chance to start yet (look at the source code for `isTerminated` to see why).

So in fact your process is inactive and will be properly garbage collected once you let go of the reference, which for your purposes should be as good as "terminated".

(Disclaimer: I was looking at the Squeak code, not Pharo, but this part of the system should be pretty much the same)

Comment: Makes sense. The code in Squeak and Pharo seems to be pretty much identical there. If I can rely on GC then terminating while the delay is running is also possible (the delay will be suspended). One question though: are the process queues weak? Their reference to the process should not hinder GC; I didn't find out where the instance variable `quiescentProcessLists` of `ProcessorScheduler` is initialized.

Comment: The process lists are not weak, but suspending takes a process of these lists. Only runnable processes are in there. `quiescentProcessLists` is never initialized, it was initialized once in 1996 or even earlier. Squeak is always running, and just temporarily paused in the middle of operations by being snapshotted to disk and resumed. Unlike most other systems it is never restarted "from scratch".

Comment: I should have guessed that :) Thanks!